# Time complexity for my solution to all permutations of integer array containing distinct numbers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, permutation

What's the time complexity of my code? I ran this through www.leetcode.com and it's optimal. I think its O(n*n!). First I thought it was O(n^2*n!) : The extra n since we make n recursive calls. However, only the first call to permute() is dominant, and kind of dwarfs the rest since n! is >>> (n-1)!

Thanks upfront!

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        return permute(nums, nums.length - 1);
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums, int n) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        if(n < 0) {
            List<Integer> permutation = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            result.add(permutation);
            return result;
        }

        // below returns (n-1)! results of size n-1 each
        List<List<Integer>> prefixes = permute(nums, n-1); 
        for(List<Integer> prefix : prefixes) {
            List<List<Integer>> permutations = insert(nums[n], prefix);
            result.addAll(permutations);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // O(n^2) worst case when size of list is n-1
    private List<List<Integer>> insert(int num, List<Integer> list) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> clone = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            clone.addAll(list);
            clone.add(i, num);
            result.add(clone);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this question might be more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/